# Most efficient way to use first column of file1 as prefix for all lines in file2

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files with equal amount of lines. I want to add each value of column 1 to become the prefix of each line in file 2 and separate each value of file2 by one whitespace.
File2 is very large and has more than 70 million columns.

Example:
Input file 2

```
10000
10019
```

Input file 1

```
Ind1
Ind2
```

Output

```
Ind1 1 0 0 0 0 
Ind2 1 0 0 1 9
```

**Q: How can this be done efficiently?**

EDIT I : I already looked for solutions to add different prefixes to each line e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/663532/how-do-i-add-a-different-prefix-to-each-line) but was unable to adjust the solution so that I can iterate over the values of the first column of another file.

EDIT II :
Using the answer from @Gilles I came up with this:

```
awk ' { print $1 } ' file1 <(sed 's/./& /g' file2) > output
```

EDIT III:
I tried the solution from @Gilles and it failed with a regex input buffer error:

```
paste -d ' ' file1 <(sed 's/./& /g' file2) > file3 
sed: regex input buffer length larger than INT_MAX
```

I also tried the solution from @Ed Morton but this ended in an OOM error. AWK states that it needs 1.8TB RAM for this operation.

```
awk '{head=$0} (getline tail < "file2") > 0{gsub(/./," &",tail); print head tail}' file1 > file3
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file1.txt FNR=1) fatal: builtin.c:3058:sub_common: buf: cannot reallocate 1949336035328 bytes of memory: Cannot allocate memory.
```

Comment: Done! Also edited the example file names. I mixed up the descirptions and the examples.

Comment: Also added a working example based on the solution from @Gilles Quenot.

Comment: You say '70 million columns' — does that mean that the lines in the file are 70 million characters each (and will become 140 million characters long when they are separated by spaces)?  Or is the total file 70 MiB with some indeterminate but much smaller number of lines?  Or something else altogether?

Comment: The lines in file2 have 70 million columns so 70 millions characters each line. So there will be 140 million after seperation.

Comment: Ouch!  GNU utilities will probably handle lines that long; you might easily run into problems on other platforms with lines that long.  You will need to test to ensure that things work OK.  Thank you for clarifying, though.

Comment: The script under `EDIT II`, i.e. `awk ' { print $1 } ' file1 <(sed 's/./& /g' file2)`, wouldn't do what you asked for.

Comment: The answer from @Gilles Quenot seems to be the correct one. Very fast solution. But anyone feel free to post a more efficient solution! I will accept his answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed` & `paste`:

```
$ paste -d '' file2 <(sed 's/./& /g' file1) 
Ind1 1 0 0 0 0 
Ind2 1 0 0 1 9
```

Comment: you could get rid of the trailing blank with `paste -d '' file2 <(sed 's/./ &/g' file1)`

Comment: … or with `paste -d ' ' file2 <(sed -e 's/./& /g; s/ $//' file1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{head=$0} (getline tail < "file2") > 0{gsub(/./," &",tail); print head tail}' file1
Ind1 1 0 0 0 0
Ind2 1 0 0 1 9
```

or if the whole contents of file1 fit in memory:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0; next} {gsub(/./," &"); print a[FNR], $0}' file1 file2
```

Comment: `awk` v00d00. Wow, impressive :D

Comment: Good solution. I will benchmark this one against the one from Gilles and report back!

Comment: I have 128 GB RAM and a 500GB swapfile and I still sometimes get to see OOM errors but this time this should be good. I will give your other solution also a try. Despite loading files into the swapfile can be kinda time consuming.